# x86 Assembly: Having hard time finding ideas for an infinite loop challenge

Tags: assembly, x86-16, corewars

I'm going to intend a competition similar to "corewars" with my friends (We are using the same memory grid as the original game)

In the game each one of us supposes to write a "safe" which is an infinite loop that is not longer then 25 lines. each "safe" has a trick or a code that can stop the loop, hence breaking the "safe". for example:

```
;Safe
safe:
    mov ax, [1000]
    cmp ax, 9999
    jne safe
```

This safe can be broken if we pass the correct code (9999) to the [1000], which will break the safe:

```
;Breaker
mov ax, 9999
mov [1000], ax
breaker: jmp breaker
```

I was thinking about making some sort of a mathematical equation, and then use it's result as the code for the safe, but I don't have any good ideas which are both short and interesting.

I'm not sure if this question is relevant to this stack site, so if it isn't I would like to know the better stack site for this kind of problem.

Comment: Funny idea, but give us some more context. You tagged [emu8086], does it mean you are restricted to run the code in that emulator? For example: `safe: rdrand / jc safe` is short and can be broke under very specific and technical conditions but can't run on emu8086. Other ideas: compute a crypto function (eg: hash, decrypt) on the input and check it against a constant. Compute the Rienman-Zeta on the input and exit iif the result is zero (and not along the trivial line). Usually a simple mangling algo works good if the challenge is about RE rather than math skills.

Comment: We are restricted to the emulator8086. I thought about making a rol encryption aswell. But I still cannot understand how can I make the key for it ( to check if my safe works ). I've never heard of Rienman-Zeta, so i'll check it right now. Thank you! 

I also really like that short thing that you've shown at the start. Do you maybe know about things similar to that that are working on the emu8086?

Comment: I've never really used emu8086 but why not starting from [xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift)? Copy the C implementation, set the seed to a known value e run it. Copy the output. Then implement it in assembly in your safe and add a test to check if its output is equal to the output of before. If not jump back to the xorshift. This way the players have to 1) figure out the algoritm of xorshift (which is simple enough) 2) Write a program to bruteforce the seed.

Comment: @MargaretBloom that you for you suggestion! I'll try that right now.

Comment: @MargaretBloom ehmm do you happen to have any implementation of such xorshift? I haven't found any good examples of it. :(

Comment: I sketched a proof of concept [here](https://pastebin.com/QQ47kM1r). See if you can put it to use.

Comment: @MargaretBloom wow! Thank you very much! My only concern is that I'm probably doing something wrong because when I put the value 0x241 in 1000 (by doing mov [1000], 0x241 ) and then putting 0f2d0h as the secret code ( cmp ax, 0f2d0h ) The loop doesn't break. I'm debugging it right now

Comment: I haven't even assembled the code :) Just wrote it while doing some other work. Fixing it is left as an exercise.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: careful with `rdrand`: some CPUs with RDRAND reportedly can't exhaust the buffer and get it to return an error (CF=1).  e.g. IvyBridge, first gen with RDRAND.  [What are the exhaustion characteristics of RDRAND on Ivy Bridge?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14413839).  But yes, reportedly later uarches can see occasional CF=1 returns; @ jww has reported that an infinite retry loop seems better than any small finite retry count to avoid spurious failures leading to error reports from users of libcrypto++.  Apparently HW with a perma-broken RDRAND hasn't been a problem getting stuck.

Comment: @Kidsm: another possible StackExchange sites for this question: [Code Golf & Coding Challenges SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).  Otherwise here is probably best. [ReverseEngineering.SE](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com) is also a possibility since the idea is to create a "safe" that's hard to reverse, i.e. hard to determine the key.  Retrocomputing isn't a good; emu8086 isn't real hardware and the question is about programming, not about old real systems.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for showing me those sites and for the help! :D